# ValueError: time data '140120 1520' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, csv, timestamp

I got this error

```
ValueError: time data '140120 1520' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

I had a csv file which I had to store in db. the data in csv file looks

```
# date   day  time   rec_no   tem        X        Z             G       

140120    20  1520   920      0.00       0.0    51           0.00         
140120    20  1521   921      37.73      46     -596.05      1.21     
140120    20  1522   922      31.11      42     31.4000      0.50      
140120    20  1523   923      0.00       0.0    -451.50      0.00         
140120    20  1524   924      0.00       0.0    -31.500      0.00
```

my problem is that I have to combine the first column (date) and 3rd column (time)  and to convert it to timestamp according to epoch time before storing in MySQL database. 
the date format from sensor, which we get in csv file is

```
140120 
14 represent 2014, 01 represent the month (January) and 20 represent day.
```

the time is

```
1520
15 represent hour and 20 represent minute. and nothing for seconds 
so we can append 00 for seconds.
```

where day columns consists of same information as in date last 2 digits, so i neglect this column (day).
So in order to convert into timestamp, I need to combine the date and time columns. and i did this and then rebuild the list as shown in my code.

I search over  net and found different techniques to convert date and time format but no command or solution is according to my need. 
my code to get data for above csv file and to convert timestamp is as follow.

```
with open(item[1]) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for k, line in enumerate(lines):
        if k >= (int(skip_header_line) + int(index_line_number)):
            data_tmp = line.split() 
            print data_tmp  # i got ['140120', '20', '1520', '920', '0.00', '0.0', '51', '0.00', '0', '0.00', '0', '0.00']
            newcolumn = data_tmp[0] + ' ' + data_tmp[2]
            data = [newcolumn] + data_tmp[3:] # re-build the list so we get 
                                              ['140120 1520', '920', '0.00', '0.0', '-31.50', '0.00', '0', '0.00', '0', '0.00']

            strDate = data[0].replace("\"", "")
            print strDate  # i got here  140120 1520
            timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate,
                                                   '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            ts = calendar.timegm(timestamp.timetuple())
            data_buffer = []
            for val in data_tmp:
                if val == " ":
                    val = None
                    data_buffer.append(val)
                else:
                    data_buffer.append(float(val))
            cursor.execute(add_data, data_buffer)
            cnx.commit()

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

If somebody give me a hint or example to convert '140120 1520' to timestamp, I would extremely thankful because I had no clue how to deal with this problem.  thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `'%y%m%d %H%M'`. Something worth pointing out is that you need to use `%y` instead of `%Y` in order to match years without the century, like '14' for 2014.

```
from datetime import datetime

s = '140120 1520'
print(datetime.strptime(s, '%y%m%d %H%M'))
```

**Output**

```
2014-01-20 15:20:00
```

Comment: thanx for the reply. I will try this on my above mention code and will come back soon.

Comment: Now I am getting another problem

ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 140120 1520

Can you please make these changes in my above mention code. I think I am making some silly mistake. thanx a lot for the help

Comment: @Rio Please update your code in your original post to reflect what you're trying right now.

Comment: I update my question with new error. I will really thankful for your help.

Comment: @Rio You didn't update your code (you're still showing the wrong time format string, for instance).

Comment: sorry for my mistake. I will do it and will come back in a while. accept my apology .

Comment: I am accepting your answer because it solved my problem of timestamp. but if you see my code and question. I think I am making some silly mistake. if help would be appreciated because it will save my whole day. thanx.

Comment: @Rio Sorry, it's too difficult to follow along with your code to address your next problem. Try submitting it as a new question with as much detail about your new error as possible. I will roll back your post to the previous version that exposed the time string formatting problem.

Comment: thanx a lot. I will make it a new question. you are right. thanx for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
print datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate,'%y%m%d %H%M')
```

For more [reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Edit:
update the full code

140120 1520 is not a float value

remove the space

Comment: thanx a lot for the reply. your solution seems to be working also but i am getting another error now. ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 140120 1520.........